# random data production in feature steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fabrication-gem, spinach

```
class Spinach::Features::Signup < Spinach::FeatureSteps

  attr_accessor :valid_attributes
  before do
    valid_attributes = Fabricate.attributes_for(:identity)
    #@valid_attributes = Fabricate :identity
  end

  step 'I am a visitor' do
    true
    visit root_path
  end

  step 'I am on the landing page' do
    current_path.must_equal root_path
  end

  step 'I follow signup link' do
    click_link('signup_link')
  end

  step 'I fill name with my name' do
    fill_in 'name', with: valid_attributes.name
  end

  step 'I fill email with my email' do
    fill_in "email", with: valid_attributes.email
  end
end
```

i use spinach gem for creating feature steps. above code id my feature steps. i also use minitest for testing framework. i use fabricator gem for creating random datas.

```
require "ffaker"
Fabricator(:identity) do
  name            {Faker::Name.name}
  email           {Faker::Internet.email}
  password_digest "ChtUIGTiBvrm6v6R4PX6sO3netSuN3eW0AbFmXblXvgKM5Z8sFUKy"
end
```

this is my fabricator class for identity model. when i run signup feature, i see an error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

i think that it is about Fabricate.Attributes_for. if i use Fabricate :identity, it doesn't give error.

i couldn't solve this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please don;t forget to accept the answer if it answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
valid_attributes = Fabricate.attributes_for(:identity)
```

You've got a `Hash`.

So do: `valid_attributes[:email]` or use an Openstruct.

Comment: i used like "valid_attributes[:email]". but this time, it gives "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error.